# nginx не прокидывает внешний ip адрес на Django или на Gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, ip, proxy

Nginx не прокидывает  внешний ip адрес на Django или на Gunicorn. Сервак за натом, нат настроен коректно, без nginx Django внешние ip адреса веб клиентов видит хорошо.

```
April 18, 2016 - 08:43:49
Django version 1.9.5, using settings 'Project1.settings'
Starting development server at http://192.168.4.102:80/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
user from 217.118.78.125
Saint Petersburg
```

Ставлю перед ним Nginx (192.168.4.102:80) проксирую на  Django или Gunicorn. (127.0.0.1:8000)

ip адре отображается  на Django 127.0.0.1 ,

```
user from 127.0.0.1
```

а на Nginx

```
217.118.78.125 - - [18/Apr/2016:08:52:20 +0300] "GET /static/img/img.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://saint-petersburg.master51.ru/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; Lenovo S860 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.105 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

conf Nginxa

```
server {

    listen 192.168.4.102:80;
    server_name master51.ru murmansk.master51.ru *.master51.ru; 
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/xmaster/PycharmProjects/project1/;

        expires 30d;
    }
#
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; 
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Настраивать django. Вот эта директива `proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;` прокидывает адрес клиента в виде заголовка `X-Real-IP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо смотреть по ключам в request.Meta: 'REMOTE_ADDR', 'HTTP_X_REAL_IP' и 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.

Ссылка на подобный вопрос на английском языке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django

Пример функции получения IP из запроса (взято из ответа по ссылке):

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

В коде не учтены некоторые моменты, например, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR может вернуть внутренний IP клиента. Также в этом заголовке запроса может содержаться поддельный IP.

Comment: публикуя ответ, старайтесь добавлять сам ответ, а не только ссылку, которая может стать недоступной

Comment: Благодарю , заработало корректно !

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл большую статью об этой проблеме, также  поясняющею данный вопрос которая раскладывает всё по косточкам (спасибо Chikiro),  что натолкнул на данную тематику , выкладывать всю статью не буду (большая),
 просто оставю тут ссылку, малоли кто нибудь сталкнёться с этими же граблями что и я.

http://phpfaq.ru/tech/ip

кстати  этих граблей можно было избежать если использовать обратное проксирование
http://ashep.org/2011/nginx-obratnyj-proksi-server/#.VxXH5Sa1lhE