# Ошибка при деплое с помощью uWSGI

Tags: django, vps, развертывание, vds, uwsgi

Попробовал задеплоить работающий(на локалке) проект
При попытке запуска через `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` -  все работает
Но как только я пытаюсь через uWSGI командой `uwsgi --http :8005 --module main.wsgi` запустить проект, то в браузерной консоли разработчика выдает следующие ошибки:
[image]

Проблема в подключении css и js, хотя через "обычный метод" - все работает
Использовал `python manage.py collectstatic` - и оно собирало(т.к. я задал в настройках) в папке static, в которой были все статические файлы
С чем может быть связана данная проблема и как можно ее решить?

Comment: Django не будет раздавать статику за пределами окружения разработчика. Вам нужно опубликовать папку static каким-нибудь другим способом, например через nginx

Comment: самое забавное, что я всегда оттягиваю подачу вопроса на стек оверфлоу, а когда подаю, дохожу до решения за минут 10(провернно на последних 3 вопросах), но все-равно - спасибо)

Comment: Так поделитесь решением, раз оно есть. Если уж задали вопрос.. :) Кому то пригодится.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич andreymal уже ответил на него. Проблема в том, что uWSGI - не видит статику и ему ее нужно передать через nginx.

Comment: Я попозже оформлю полноценный ответ наверно

Comment: @nrjshka лично я обычно ставлю django на apache2, потому знаю что там тоже такое бывает. Интересно было бы увидеть решение с ngnix :)

Answer (score 0):

[Официальная документация Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/) заявляет ([перевод](https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/howto/static-files/index.html)):

> Кроме конфигурации, необходимо настроить раздачу статических файлов.
>
> При разработке, если вы используете `django.contrib.staticfiles`, это все происходит автоматически через `runserver`, при `DEBUG` равной `True`.
>
> Это представление **очень неэффективно** и, возможно, **небезопасно**. Оно предназначено только для разработки, и **не должно использоваться на боевом сервере**.

Соответственно, Django не собирается раздавать статические файлы через `uwsgi` (хотя её можно заставить это сделать, но не буду рассказывать как, потому что не надо).

В общем-то про раздачу статических файлов на продакшене тоже есть [страница](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/deployment/) в документации ([перевод](https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/howto/static-files/deployment.html)).

В большинстве случаев перед джангой (да и вообще любыми другими скриптами) ставят nginx (даже если есть apache2, перед ним чаще всего тоже стоит nginx). И в конфигурации nginx прописывают, что для ссылок на статические файлы нужно забрать их из такого-то каталога, а всё остальное передавать в Django. Я не буду расписывать здесь целый мануал по настройке nginx (это легко гуглится), но типичный конфиг выглядит примерно так:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  # listen, ssl_certificate и прочие параметры тут

  # Статические файлы забирает сам nginx
  location /static/ {
    alias /path/to/your/static/;
    # Можно управлять кэшем браузера с помощью параметра expires
  }

  location /media/ {
    alias /path/to/your/media/;
    expires 30d;  # предлагаем браузеру кэшировать файлы из /media/ месяц
  }

  # Всё остальное передаём в Django, на порту 8000 запущен uwsgi
  location {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    include proxy_params;
  }
}
```

Если вам нужен IP-адрес пользователя (клиента), то учтите, что клиентом для Django в таком случае оказывается nginx с IP-адресом 127.0.0.1, и [вам придётся узнавать реальный IP пользователя обходными путями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514072).