# Python / django / получение ip посетителя

Tags: python, django, ip

Подскажите как получить ip пользователя?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514072

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search/?clid=2186621&text=django%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20ip%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F&lr=213&redircnt=1562581457.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Вольный перевод [англоязычного](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581997/11558617) ответа на Ваш вопрос:*

```py
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

Убедитесь, что обратный прокси (если есть) настроен правильно (например, `mod_rpaf` установлен для Apache).

Примечание: выше используется **первый** элемент `X-Forwarded-For`, но вы можете использовать **последний** элемент (например, в случае Heroku: [получить реальный IP-адрес клиента на Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264304/get-clients-real-ip-address-on-heroku#answer-18517550))

А затем просто передайте запрос в качестве аргумента;

```py
get_client_ip(request)
```